# Nav element goes below header

Tags: html, css

So i have been struggling a bit with a problem of mine. First my Nav bar will for the life of me not go Into the header element. my picture element (#Billede div box) seems to be affected by this since i've only given it a height and width, but it scaled all the way to the left and is there to stay.
Any tips?

```css
nav,
li,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-rigth: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  color: rgb(255, 46, 248);
}

form {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  margin-right: 400px;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

textarea[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  resize: none;
}

button[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 45, 248);
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Billede {
  height: 60px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Mike's Portfolio</h1>
  <nav>
    <li><a href="#">Opgaver</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Om Mig</a></li>
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="Info"></div>

<div id="Billede"><img src="../../Images/Billede.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: can you please show us where you want the navbar

Comment: https://gyazo.com/0297e0242ce38aede46dc5230e2337a4

right now the nav bar is not even inside the header, and it has extended that page.

Comment: you want the nav in the same line as your site title??

Comment: yes. the problem is, is that it is not even within the "box" of the header as the title.

Answer (score 1):

is this how you want this??.. `h1` is a blog element so it it takes full width that is why `nav` comes on the next line. hope it helps

your image moved to right because your image is wrapped with `a` and `a` has `float: right` css

```
nav, li, a {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right; //this
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```css
nav, li, a{
   text-decoration: none;
   list-style-type: none;
   float: right; 
   margin-bottom: 10px; 
   padding: 5px;
  }

  header{
   width: 80%;
   height: 100px;
   margin-rigth: 10%;
   margin-left: 10%;
   color: rgb(255, 46, 248);
  }

  form{
   margin-top: 100px;
   width: 800px;
   margin-right: 400px;
  }

  input[type=text], select {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 12px 20px;
     margin: 8px 0;
     display: inline-block;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-radius: 4px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    textarea[type=text], select{
     width: 100%;
     padding: 12px 20px;
     margin: 8px 0;
     display: inline-block;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-radius: 4px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     float: left;
     resize: none;
    }

    button[type=submit] {
     width: 100%;
     background-color: rgb(255, 45, 248);
     color: white;
     padding: 14px 20px;
     margin: 8px 0;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 4px;
     cursor: pointer; 
    }

    #Billede{
     height: 60px;
     width: 30px;
    }

h1{
  display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <h1>Mike's Portfolio</h1>
 <nav>
  <li><a href="#">Opgaver</li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Om Mig</li>
 </nav>
</header>

<div id="Info"></div>

<div id="Billede"><img src="../../Images/Billede.jpg"</div>
```

Comment: ah yes, that fixed it. thanks alot. there is a second problem now, which i thought would be fixed from fixing the nav bar. 

The image that is linked in the code too, is for some reason forced all the way to the right? (not from your code, since it was so at the beginning). It was fine when i put it in, but when i gave it a height and width, it forced itself to the right and extended the page. any ideas?

Comment: you're saying that i should remove Float: right? if i do that then the nav bar will not be on line with the title

Comment: Nevermind, i found a solution for it. thanks for the help on the other part

Comment: @Mike skovby can you please tell me what you did for it